# ec2 security group and Iptables

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I have assigned the security group to ec2 and then configured iptables so does security group will be effective or iptables will be effective?

Both have different inbound and outbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, security group will be effective, first your security group rules take effect before traffic reaches your instance, and then iptables rules are applied by your operating system.